# How to remove ssl certificate from opencart project?

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, opencart, opencart2.3

I have one openCart project that runs on live server very fine.

But when I'm trying to run it on my localhost it redirects to https://www.localhost/dashboard/ , I don't no what wrong.

I have made all necessary changes in `config.php` file.
Here is my `config.php` file :

```
$root = 'http://localhost/folder_name/';
$url = 'http://localhost/folder_name';

$projectpath = 'http://localhost/folder_name/';


$path = str_replace("index.php","",str_replace($root, "", $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
$url2= $url.$path;
$rootfolder = $root.$path;


define('HTTP_SERVER', $url2);

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', $url2);*/

define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost/folder_name/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://localhost/folder_name/');
define('HTACCESS','folder_name/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost/folder_name/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://localhost/folder_name/');

// DIR
define('ROOT_APPLICATION', $root .$projectpath);
define('PROJECT_PATH', $projectpath);
define('MAIN_URL', $url.$projectpath);
define('ROOT_URL', $url2);
define('DIR_APPLICATION', $rootfolder.'catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', $rootfolder.'system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', $rootfolder.'catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', $rootfolder.'catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', $rootfolder.'system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', $root.$projectpath.'image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', $rootfolder.'system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', $rootfolder.'system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', $rootfolder.'system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', $rootfolder.'system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_store', $rootfolder.'system/storage/');
define('TEMPLATE_PATH', $root.$projectpath);
```

Here is my `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]

RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]

RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]

#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]    

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/$1 [R=301,L]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the .htaccess:

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled.

# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.

# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /folder_name/
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# NOTE this account's php is controlled via FPM and the vhost, this is a place holder.
# Do not edit. This next line is to support the cPanel php wrapper (php_cli).
# AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .phtml
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

and find the variable($_['site_ssl']) in folder of opencart set to false in localhost.(folder_name/system/config/admin.php and config.php)

```
$_['site_ssl'] = false;
```